# OData 6.0 missing ODataEntityTypeSerializer

Tags: odata, upgrade, compatibility

I am trying to upgrade OData package (`Microsoft.AspNet.OData`) from v5.9 to v6.0 and my code break because I have a class that extends `ODataEntityTypeSerializer`.

I search for that in object browser and it was removed. When I back to v5.9.1 it works.

Is there a replacement for `ODataEntityTypeSerializer` in new 6.0 version or this is just a compatibility break?

My derived class is a way to prevent `null` value serialization.
I write the new provider to treat `null` based on [this response on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863111/how-to-ignore-null-values-while-serializing-odata-response#25538322).

```
 public class NullEntityTypeSerializer : ODataEntityTypeSerializer
    {
        public NullEntityTypeSerializer(ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            : base(serializerProvider)
        { }

        public override void WriteObjectInline(object graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
        {
            if (graph != null)
            {
                base.WriteObjectInline(graph, expectedType, writer, writeContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE (jul/18):** The problem with `SingleResult.Create()` that generate this work around was fixed in v7.0 and this is not necessary anymore. Check https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/170

Comment: @OP did you manage to come right with a replacement?

Comment: I´m still in v5.9

Comment: In v7.0 the orginal problem was fixed. check the question.update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://odata.github.io/WebApi/#07-18-6-0
You should use ODataResourceSerializer.

Comment: Not so good... =). I migrate to new `Serializer`, but they change `DefaultODataSerializerProvider` constructor that requires a service provider now. The [work arround here](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#10-02-work-around-for-singleresult-create) don't work anymore. Looking for new fixes...

Comment: With the new version you have to add all the providers through dependency injection. In your case it shold be something like: ``config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "api", builder =>
    builder.AddService(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => edmModel)
    .AddService<ODataSerializerProvider>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton,
    sp=> new YourODataSerializerProvider(sp)));``

Comment: I see that v6 introduce a new argument on `MapODataServiceRoute` and [this page with information about DI in v6](https://odata.github.io/WebApi/13-04-DependencyInjection/). I will try to figure out and implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the same issue here: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/995

You call this method to get the IServiceProvider: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/src/System.Web.OData/Extensions/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs#L234

And also need a custom IContentNegotiator