# How to ignore null properties in HttpApplication json response in .Net Framework

Tags: c#, json, odata, httpresponse, json-serialization

Same question as

[How to Ignore Null values while serializing OData response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863111/how-to-ignore-null-values-while-serializing-odata-response)

and

[.NET Core: Remove null fields from API JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595027/net-core-remove-null-fields-from-api-json-response)

Only difference is how to do it in .NetFramework 4.7.2 with HttpApplication.

Tried the attached solutions but they are for different .Net flavors.

Comment: At least the first one ***IS*** for the "legacy", classic, Windows-only .NET framework .... that should really work just fine.

Comment: That is using AspNet libs. My project is using System.Web.HttpApplication and System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration. I need a solution using those.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.